# Valgrind reports a SQLite error, why?

Tags: c, sqlite

Valgrind reports a SQLite error:

```
==11614== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==11614==    at 0x0: ???
==11614==    by 0x6E8CF: sqlite3MallocSize (sqlite3.c:19034)
==11614==    by 0x6E472: mallocWithAlarm (sqlite3.c:18870)
==11614==    by 0x6E520: sqlite3Malloc (sqlite3.c:18895)
==11614==    by 0x6ED56: sqlite3MallocZero (sqlite3.c:19159)
==11614==    by 0x6DA46: pthreadMutexAlloc (sqlite3.c:18039)
==11614==    by 0x6D779: sqlite3MutexAlloc (sqlite3.c:17353)
==11614==    by 0xFA4B7: sqlite3_initialize (sqlite3.c:112588)
==11614==    by 0xFD895: openDatabase (sqlite3.c:114531)
==11614==    by 0xFDF13: sqlite3_open (sqlite3.c:114780)
==11614==    by 0x579C1: SqlLiteConnection_Connect(char*) (SqlLite.cpp:14)
==11614==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I am passing a valid value to `sqlite3_open`. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

P.S. I am using the SQLite Amalgamation version 3.7.11. I am running Mac OSX 10.7.3. SQLite was compiled with `gcc -c -g -m32 sqlite3.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem with valgrind 3.7.0. After upgrading to 3.8.1, the problem disapeared.